# Class A instance containing a collection of instances of class B. Best way (performance) to access class A property from any given instance of B

Tags: c#, parent-child, algorithmic-trading

I am building a trading application that uses market depth data. Each **market depth** update consists of a number of **pricelevels** and each of theseconsists of **orders** - these form the **orderbook**. I need the **order** class to be as small as possible, because there will be thousands of instances of them - containing the information about the price and size preferrably. The reason is that there are many orders in a given orderbook and my app uses many different orderbooks from various **asset pairs** on various **exchanges**.

During runtime, I query the orders from an exchange API and internally build the orderbook. Thus, each order is tied to a given orderbook (for set pair name and exchange). Thus, the orderbook is *built* from the individual order *elements*, but has some  additional pieces of information on top.

Some methods of the app need to access exchange name or pair name from given instance of **order**. Since each order is "tied" to an orderbook, I want the orderBook to hold this information instead of all of the orders needing to copy this. What is the best way to achieve this, if I do not want each order to hold these information due to performance (memory needs especially)?

Thoughts:

1. Use events - the orderbook will subscribe to events for every one of its member orders. The subclass will fire when the property from the other class is needed?
2. "Tie" each order to the "parent" orderbook and access its properties via a method/property. I am not sure about the terminology (help please), as parent-child is connected to inheritance, while the relationship I have in mind is more like a leaf to a branch.
3. Forget about it and just keep the information in each given order, copied across all of them. Maybe I am just overthinking the optimization.

I am looking for

- either an answer to pick 1-3 with a hint to implementation
- or, better, a way to test which of these is the best performance-wise. How can I stage a stress test to test which of these take most CPU, memory? I have never tried to build something like this, so any help would be appreciated.
- Lastly, I am not sure about the correct terminology (parent-child is inheritance, while branch-leaf is what?), thus even this might help me make my search more efficient. How can I search/name this kind of relationship I need to implement?

**EDIT1**
As per comments: I would lke to test the performance. I do not know how though - given that as of yet I do not know how to implement the method in any of the ways. Secondly, once I do, what are the tools to test CPU and memory needs? I have never done this, basically I just timed tests. Do I look for something in Visual Studio or should I use other tools?

Minimal example:

```
public class A
{
    List<B> instancesOfB;
    public string PropertyOfInterest { get; set; }

    public A(B someB, B anotherB, string propertyString)
    {
        PropertyOfInterest = propertyString;
        instancesOfB = new List<B>();
        instancesOfB.Add(someB);
        instancesOfB.Add(anotherB);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public string GetPropertyFromA()
    {
        // TODO: how?
        // fire an event that class A will subscribe to when B is added to it?
        // any other way?
        throw new NotFiniteNumberException();
    }
}
public class  ExecutionClass
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = new B();
        A a = new A(b1, b2, "texOfInterest");

        string someText = b1.GetPropertyFromA(); // Should equal to "textOfInterest"
    }
}
```

Example:

```
 public class TestOrder
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Size { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public MarketSide Side { get; set; }

    public TestOrder(decimal price, decimal size, DateTime timeStamp, MarketSide side)
    {
        Price = Price;
        Size = size;
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        Side = side;
    }

    public string GetPairName()
    {
        //TODO: how?
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ExchangeName GetExchangeName()
    {
        // TODO: how?
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public decimal GetTickSize()
    {
        // TODO how?
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void PrintSomeOrderInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", this.GetExchangeName().ToString(), this.Size, this.GetTickSize());
    }
}

public class Pricelevel
{
    List<TestOrder> orders;
    public Pricelevel() { }

    public void AddOrder(TestOrder order)
    {
        orders.Add(order);
    }
}

public class Assetpair
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ExchangeName ExchangeName { get; set; }
    public decimal TickSize { get; set; }

    public Assetpair(string name, ExchangeName exchange, decimal tickSize)
    {
        Name = name;
        ExchangeName = exchange;
        TickSize = tickSize;
    }
}

public class Orderbook
{
    Dictionary<MarketSide, Dictionary< decimal, PriceLevel>> OrderBookDict; // side is either asks or bids
    public ExchangeName ExchangeName { get; set; }
    public AssetPair PairInfo { get; set; }

    public Orderbook(Assetpair pairInfo, List<Pricelevel> asks, List<Pricelevel> bids)
    {

    }

    public void AddOrder(TestOrder order)
    {
        // TODO: search the nested dictionary according to price property of the order
        // Add to given pricelevel and update the pricelevel in the orderbook
    }

    public void AddPriceLevel(PriceLevel level)
    {
        // TODO: Search for given pricelevel according to price - add on the correct position
    }
}

public class ExecutionClass
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        TestOrder order1 = new TestOrder(price: 11.2m, size: 100.23m, timeStamp: DateTime.Now, side: MarketSide.MarketAsk);
        Pricelevel level1 = new Pricelevel();
        level1.AddOrder(order1);
        List<Pricelevel> asks = new List<Pricelevel> { level1/*, level2, ...*/ };
        List<Pricelevel> bids = new List<Pricelevel> { /*level3, level4, ...*/};

        Assetpair assetPair = new Assetpair("pairOne", ExchangeName.None, 0.01m);
        Orderbook book1 = new Orderbook(assetPair, asks, bids);

        // print info contained in the book1 where order1 belongs
        // trivial example - need to do more advanced stuff
        order1.PrintSomeOrderInfo();
    }        
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] (with **much** less code than you have now in your question).

Comment: You want to know performance, do up some test cases... Then test them

Comment: @mjwills Added a hopefully minimal example.

Comment: @TheGeneral I am looking for ideas how to implement the methods. If I do not know how to do it, I have nothing to test. Secondly, I have never done testing like this before and I am looking for tips how to do this.

Comment: Keep a reference  to the orderbook in the order.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for the idea. I thought about this. If I understand correctly, each order will have a field/property OrderBook equal to null until it is added to the OrderBook. At this point the property will be changed to a reference of the OrderBook adding the order. Is this correct? Would it not use even more space than the string property? If each Order needs to have a OrderBook field/property, this seems to me to be bigger than the string. Am I missing something?

Comment: You said there were multiple properties from the orderbook that you needed, not just one string. Also, if the string changes, you'll have to update every order if each order has their own copy.

Comment: @RaymondChenYou are right about multiple properties, I oversimplified - there are four strings/decimals. Good point with the changes too. What I want to understand is, how much memory is allocated to each OrderderBook field in a given Order. Given that the OrderBook class contains also Dictionary with number of items, my thoughts were that this would be rather big. How does C# allocate memory at the Order object initialization (without setting the OrderBook field)?

Comment: You aren't putting a copy of the OrderBook in the Order. You're putting a *reference* to the OrderBook in the Order. If it were a copy, then none of this would work. (You would change a property in the OrderBook, but the Order wouldn't see it because it would be operating on a separate copy.)